# why $\sin 2πx$ is strictly monotonic?

Tags: general-topology, trigonometry, monotone-functions

I have some confusion in **Munkres** book

My confusion given below  marked in red colour

[image]

My confusion :why $\sin 2πx$ is strictly monotonic on such an interval?.

My thinking : Take $x=0 $  and $x=1$ , then $f(x)= \sin 2 \pi x$  will not be strictly monotonic  since $f(0)=f(1)=0$

Comment: How is $\bar{V}_n$ defined?

Comment: Note that $[0,1]$ is not such an interval.

Comment: @VIVID $\overline{V_n}$ is standard notation for the closure of $V_n$, which is defined in the preceding line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$\overline{V_n}=\overline{\left(n-\frac14,n+\frac14\right)}=\left[n-\frac14,n+\frac14\right]$$and that $x\in\left[n-\frac14,n+\frac14\right]\iff2\pi x\in\left[2\pi n-\frac\pi2,2\pi n+\frac\pi2\right]$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Got  its , thanks u sir @Jose carlos

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $ f(x)=\sin(2x\pi)$.
$$x\in V_n \implies$$
$$n-\frac 14< x <n+\frac 14\implies$$

$$-\frac{\pi}{2}< 2\pi x-2n\pi < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\implies \cos(2\pi x)=\cos(2x\pi-2n\pi)>0$$

$$\implies f'(x)>0$$

$ f$ is continuous at $ \overline{V_n} \implies$

$ f $ is strictly increasing at $\overline{V_n}$.